# how to query queried resultset in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to fetch duplicate records within a time limit

my table is

```
id    designation     company     pdate            location
1     d1               c1         31-1-2014        delhi
2     d3               c1         2-2-2014         delhi
3     d5               c5         1-2-2014         chennai
4     d1               c1         12-2-2014        delhi
5     d2               c2         1-2-2014         chennai
6     d3               c1         2-2-2014         delhi
7     d3               c1         3-2-2014         delhi
8     d4               c2         2-2-2014         chennai
9     d5               c3         4-2-2014         delhi
10    d1               c4         5-2-2014         chennai
11    d1               c4         1-2-2014         delhi
12    d3               c1         2-2-2014         chennai
13    d2               c3         3-2-2014         delhi
14    d5               c5         1-2-2014         chennai

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE pdate BETWEEN  '1-2-2014' AND  '2-2-2014'group by designation, company,location order by pdate ASC, designation ASC, company ASC, location ASC
```

now i fetched records

```
id    designation     company     pdate            location
3     d2               c2         1-2-2014         chennai
4     d3               c1         2-2-2014         delhi
8     d4               c2         2-2-2014         chennai
11    d1               c4         1-2-2014         delhi
12    d3               c1         2-2-2014         chennai
14    d5               c5         1-2-2014         chennai
```

and now for every row fetched I have to query duplicate (for the value designation,company,location) records in the same table

so my final output will be

```
id    designation     company     pdate            location
2     d3               c1         2-2-2014         delhi
5     d2               c2         1-2-2014         chennai
6     d3               c1         2-2-2014         delhi
7     d3               c1         3-2-2014         delhi
8     d4               c2         2-2-2014         chennai
10    d1               c4         5-2-2014         chennai
12    d3               c1         2-2-2014         chennai
14    d5               c5         1-2-2014         chennai
```

so that in my final result I have all the values between date 1-2-2014 to 2-2-2014 and also the records with duplicate values for desination,company,location  of any date from the filtered dates records

Answer (score 0):

Use an `exists` clause:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (SELECT *
              FROM mytable t2
              WHERE pdate BETWEEN '1-2-2014' AND '2-2-2014' and
                    t2.designation = t.designation and
                    t2.company = t.company and
                    t2.location = t.location
             );
```

You really should put your date constants in the ISO standard format of YYYY-MM-DD.